# Unity3d 4.5.2 integration with monoDev

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, file-association

I am new to unity platform. I am having **visual studio 2008** and **unity 3D v4.5.2** working side by side. When ever i create a C# script and opens it to edit, it opens in visual Studio but not in monoDev even i have set the preferences to MonoDev built in and synchronized **Assets** with MonoDev. but still it opens in VS 2008. All i want is to open in MonoDev but not in VS. Ive searched it but not finding any particular solution to the problem.

Comment: are you in windows or OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity Preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor and **instead** of selecting the "Monodevelop (Built In)" option select "Browse" and go select the app exe file yourself and  to debug in Monodevelop in Unity 4.3, you need to  to tick the options **"Development Build"**, and **"Script Debugging"** in the Build Settings panel

Answer (score 0):

If you double-click a .cs file in Windows Explorer, does it open Visual Studio? If so, try making the default editor for .cs files the Mono IDE.

Hold Shift, then right-click a .vs file, then pick the "open file with" (or similar) item to permanently assign a new editor to .vs files.

Comment: i just tried it to open in unity 3d by clicking on script file

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i broke my head but found the simplest solution

please follow

1. Open Unity
2. Go to Edit (Second Tab)
3. Click on Preferences (A new Tab will open )
4. Click on External Tools (Second Option Available)
5. Choose from the list of options Available

AND YOU ARE DONE (Make sure your option of the editor is Installed first LOL)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Edit" tab:

[image: Edit Tab]

Then find "Preference" in the available options. You will find such a mini window opening up, as in the picture below:

[image: preferences window]

Then click on the second option, "External tools":

Then choose from the list of options available (if you have Mono Develop installed then it will be already selected for you)

My suggested options are:

1. Visual Studio
2. Mono Develop (usually I have to force close the first time , but I am comfortable with Mono Develop because of its light-weight and powerful performance compared to Visual Studio)
3. Notepad++ (for the pros)